# How to return correct type of data in templates?

Tags: c++, function, templates, return-type, function-templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class X, class Y>
Y big(X a, Y b)
{
   if (a > b)
      return (a);
   else return (b);
}

int main()
{
   cout << big(32.8, 9);
}
```

Here I am using templates in CPP, so when I call the function `big` bypassing arguments of `double` and `int` type, I want the return answer which is `double`. The type here, it returns `32` instead of `32.8`.

How I get my desired output?
How to write a proper return type of `big` function?

Comment: A function can only return *one* fixed type. You cannot choose at run-time what type to return.

Comment: You may want to look at how [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) is implemented. The return type of a function must be known at compile time in C++. So you can't have this return type depend on the runtime value of your parameters. This is why for such function, you need both parameters to have the same type (i.e., have type X, but not Y).

Answer (score 12):

A function can have only one return type that has to be known at compile time. However, you can use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type), to return a type that both parameters can be implicity converted to.

That would be

```
#include <type_traits>
template <class X, class Y>
typename std::common_type<X,Y>::type big(X a, Y b)
{
   if (a > b)
      return a;
   else return b;
}
```

And to check that it actually returns a `double` when passed an `int` and a `double` we can do:

```
int main() {
    auto x = big(4.2,42);
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(x),double>::value;
}
```

Which prints

```
1
```

PS: `std::common_type` can use the ternary operator behind the scences and as such this solution isnt much different from the other answers (`auto` + ternary). The real power of `std::common_type` is that it accepts any number of parameters.

Answer (score 10):

The return type must be determined at compile-time.
You can use *[trailing return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function)* with a *[conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator)*, if you are limited to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
auto big(X&& a, Y&& b) -> decltype(a > b ? a : b) // ---> like this
{
   return  a > b ? a : b;
}
```

[See live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zth3advoG9u41vfp)

---

However, if you have access to [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)  or higher `auto` return is enough, as the compiler will deduce the right type if you use it along with the conditional operator as follows:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
auto big(X a, Y b)
{
   return  a > b ? a : b;
}
```

[See live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AQB505njU89Mf3f5)

Comment: Trailing return type isn't needed, at least as of C++14.

Comment: @JeJo Yes, I suppose that is fine as well, but probably pointless, because you are not modifying either argument and the return type will still be a lvalue reference in either case (though potentially non-`const`).

Comment: I removed my comments since they don't apply anymore, but I would suggest adding a warning to the answer that you cannot take the parameters by-value.

Comment: If someone looks on your code, it seems that the passed parameter will decide which return type someone will get which is *not* the case! You always will get back a double, even if a is bigger than b.

Answer (score 5):

In marking your return type as `Y` and passing an `int` as your second parameter, you've clearly indicated that `Y` is an `int`. There's no surprises going on here.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename X, typename Y>
decltype(auto) big(const X& a, const Y& b)  // return type can just be auto as well 
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << big(32.8, 9) << '\n';
    std::cout << big(9, 32.8) << '\n';
    std::cout << big(32.8, 90) << '\n';
    std::cout << big(90, 32.8) << '\n';
}
```

This prints all four correct values to the screen.

https://godbolt.org/z/fyGsmo

One thing that's important to note is that this will only work for types that can be compared against each other, i.e., the compiler will implicitly convert one type to the other for the comparison.

**IMPORTANT**: The parameters need to be taken by reference to avoid undefined behavior. This has to do with the return type I am stubbornly sticking by. `decltype(auto)` can return references to types. If you return something local to the function (arguments count), you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @walnut Accidentally returning a reference is a lot harder than this site makes it out to be. But good to know about the undefined behavior. It's not like this would be code I'd write anyway; it's an answer to a question.

Comment: Ah. I read your earlier comment as two distinct points and not effect and cause. I can make the appropriate edit.

Comment: I've added an extra disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the correct solution for your precise situation, in all likelihood – the other answers are likely to be much closer to what you want.

However, if you *really* need to return entirely different types at runtime for some reason, the correct solution (since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)) is to use a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), which is a sort of type-safe union.

```cpp
#include <variant>

template <typename X, typename Y>
std::variant<X, Y> max(X a, Y b) {
  if (a > b)
    return std::variant<X, Y>(std::in_place_index_t<0>, a);
  else
    return std::variant<X, Y>(std::in_place_index_t<1>, b);
}
```

Note that then the onus is on the caller to deal with the returned value, most likely using [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) or the like.

Answer (score -2):

It returns int because Y is an int and it casts the 32.8 to it. When you called big 
32,82 is a float, but 8 is an int and the function return type is Y, which is also int.

You can't really fix this as you need to know at runtime which type big returns, so make a and b the same type like this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    template <typename X>

    X big (X a, X b)
    {
    if (a>b)
    return a;

    else return b;
    }

    int main()
    {
    cout<< big (32.8, 9.0);
    }
```